# Objects and composition of objects

Tags: c++

I'm coming from c#/Java/TypeScript. So do I initialise objects inside a class. For example for  a chess game. Lets say I have class for the spot on the board, the board.
So normally it will be

```
public class Piece()
{
   bool isWhite;
   Piece(isWhite){
    this.isWhite = true;
   }
}
    public class Spot(){
        Piece piece //Chess Piece
        Spot(bool isWhite)
        {
           this.piece.isWhite = isWhite;
        }
       }
```

Comment: Take a look at [member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) to see how you can write a constructor that invokes the constructors of contained objects. I'm sure there's a dupe of this somewhere on SO.

Comment: btw what is the best understandable docs for c++. I'm struggling to find a good documentation which other languages like rust/python/c# seem to have

Comment: Cppreference is pretty good in my experience

Comment: alright will have a look thank you God bless. :)

Comment: @Sam what's the question? please edit adding it

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned in the comment to your post https://cppreference.com/ is usually the best place to look up documentation.

Now about your question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Piece
{
public:
    ~Piece() = default;

    explicit Piece(bool isWhite)
    {
        this->isWhite = isWhite;
    }

    bool isWhite;
};


class Board
{
public:
    Board() = default;
    ~Board() = default;

    void addPiece(Piece p)
    {
        pieces.push_back(p);
    }

    std::vector<Piece> pieces;
};


int main()
{
    Board b;
    Piece p(true);
    b.addPiece(p);
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This is how you would usually define a class that has a member from another class.

You should definitely check out constructors and destructors in c++ as they are very important (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_constructor_destructor.htm).

And as for vector, this is a generic container from the c++ standard library.

Edit: I did indeed forget to add the default keyword to the constructor and destructor of Board which are unnecessary. The reason I've left them there is to showcase their existence to someone new to the language.

Also the reason I didn't pass the piece be reference is because references and pointers might be a complete chapter for someone new to the language.
Basically, the optimal way to write:

```
void addPiece(Piece p)
{
    pieces.push_back(p);
}
```

is:

```
void addPiece(const Piece& p)
{
    pieces.push_back(p);
}
```

Comment: That code don't even compile for the lack of empty constructor on PIece, and destructor there is unnecessary. Then in Piece other that missing constructor/destructor implementation (and both unnecessary), you're even passing piece by copy.